# how to download a file using sync webclient request in c# with out showing popup

Tags: c#, .net

I am using "webclient" to download and save a file by url in windows application.

here is my code:

```
WebClient wc = new WebClient();
wc.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Cookie, cc);
wc.DownloadFile(new Uri(e.Url.ToString()), targetPath);
```

this is working fine local system.(downloading the file and saved to target path automatically with out showing any popup).
But when i am trying to execute the .exe in server its showing save/open popup.
Is there any modifications require to download a file in server settings.
Please help me to download the file with out showing popup in server too.

thanks in advance..[image]

Comment: Can you show a screenshot of the popup?

Comment: Hi  Enigmativity,
Just now i uploaded screen shot for popup..

Comment: That's an Internet Explorer dialog. It's nothing to do with your actual code. It's not a programming issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally i got the solution for this issue..
herw the code:

```
WebClient wc = new WebClient();
wc.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Cookie, cc);
using (Stream data = wc.OpenRead(new Uri(e.Url.ToString())))
{
    using (Stream targetfile = File.Create(targetPath))
    {
       data.CopyTo(targetfile);
    }
}
```

here i just replaced the code

```
wc.DownloadFile(new Uri(e.Url.ToString()), targetPath);
```

with the blow lines:

```
using (Stream data = wc.OpenRead(new Uri(e.Url.ToString())))
{
 using (Stream targetfile = File.Create(targetPath))
 {
    data.CopyTo(targetfile);
 }
}
```

Now its working fine..
Thanks all for ur response..